# Cannot use Telnet library of Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, telnet

I found it's tricky to use telnet library in RF, I'm using serial server to link two servers, when I using 'Open Connection' with ip and port, the connection can be created, but I cannot run further keywords, including any 'write' and 'read' related keywords, when I use 'Write', the output always be:
'No match found for '
' in 10 seconds. Output:'  //10s is my set timeout

```
_Open Telnet Connection By Serial Server
[Arguments]    ${serial_ip}    ${user_name}    ${password}    ${port}    ${timeout}=10s
${output}=    Telnet.Open Connection     ${serial_ip}    port=${port}    timeout=${timeout}
Write Control Character    29     # I mean send a ^]
Telnet.Write    help
${output}=    Telnet.Read Until Regexp    .*
Log    ${output}
Telnet.Close Connection
```

here is report.html
KEYWORD Interface . _Open Telnet Connection By Serial Server ${serial_ip}, ${SERIAL_SERVER_USERNAME}, ${SERIAL_SERVER_PASSWORD}, 4001
Start / End / Elapsed:  20211206 20:37:09.101 / 20211206 20:37:19.117 / 00:00:10.016
00:00:00.002 KEYWORD ${output} = Telnet . Open Connection ${serial_ip}, port=${port}, timeout=${timeout}
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD Telnet . Write Control Character 29
00:00:10.011 KEYWORD Telnet . Write help
Documentation:

Writes the given text plus a newline into the connection.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20211206 20:37:09.105 / 20211206 20:37:19.116 / 00:00:10.011
20:37:19.116    FAIL    No match found for '
' in 10 seconds. Output:

00:00:00.000 KEYWORD ${output} = Telnet . Read Until Regexp .*

Comment: Probably is missing the definition of the Prompt.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, I tied but also no effect, now I use OperatingSystem.Run to execute telnet command directly as a workaround